# How to determine the number of bytes available before socket read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

Is it possible to determine the number of bytes available to read from a socket before attempting to read?

Example:

```
require 'socket'

client_thread = Thread.new do
  socket = nil

  begin
    socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2000)
    socket.write("Hello from client")
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    retry
  ensure
    if !socket.nil?
      if !socket.closed?
        socket.close
      end
    end
  end 
end

server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2000)
client = server.accept

read_ready = IO.select([client], nil, nil, 30)[0]
if read_ready.include?(client)
  #There is currently 17 bytes available to read, but how do I programmatically determine this?
  data = client.recv_nonblock(17)
end

client_thread.join
```

Comment: Read the [BasicSocket documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html), looking for mentions of `MSG_PEEK`. You might also benefit from reading C or C++ documentation that discusses using that flag.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me: socket.recv_nonblock(n, Socket::MSG_PEEK).bytesize returns n if there is at least n bytes available to read.